# Deploy Ansible project which include a docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-compose

I woud like to use `Ansible` to deploy one of my project (let's call it `project-to-deploy`).

`project-to-deploy` can be run locally using a `docker-compose.yml` file, which, among other things, mount the following volumes inside the `docker-container`.

```
version: "2"
services:
  database:
    image: mysql:5.6
      volumes:
        - ./docker/mysql.init.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  messages:
      image: private.repo/project-to-deploy:latest
```

Nothing more useful here. To run the project: `docker-compose up`. 
I have created a `docker image` of the project (in which I copy all the files from the project to the newly created `docker image`), and uploaded it to `private.repo/project-to-deploy:latest`.

Now comes the Ansible part. 
For the project to run, I need:

1. The docker image
2. A MySQL instance (see part of my `docker-compose.yml` below)

In my `docker-compose.yml` (above), it is quite easy to do so. I just create the 2 services (database and `project-to-deploy`) and link them each-other. 
 
How can I perform such action in `Ansible`?

First things I did is to fetch the image:

```
- name: Docker - pull project image
  docker:
    image: "private.repo/project-to-deploy:latest"
    state: restarted
    pull: always
```

Then, how can I link the MySQL docker image to this, **knowing that** the MySQL docker image need files from `project-to-deploy` ?

If you think of another way to do it, feel free to make suggestions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slight correction, the `docker` module is for running containers, in your example you are not just fetching the image. You're actually pulling the image, creating a container, and running it.

I would typically accomplish this by using ansible to template each container's config files with the needed IP addresses, ports, credentials, etc. providing them all they need to know to communicate with each other.

Since your example only involves few connections you could set the `links` option in your ansible task. You should only need to set it on the "messages" container side.

```
- name: Docker - start MySQL container
  docker:
    name: database
    image: "mysql:5.6"
    state: restarted
    volumes:
    - /path/to/docker/mysql.init.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    pull: always

- name: Docker - start project container
  docker:
    name: messages
    image: "private.repo/project-to-deploy:latest"
    state: restarted
    pull: always
    links:
    - database
```