# ansible-container database init scripts

Tags: database, initialization, ansible, ansible-container

Trying to use `ansible-container` (0.2.0) to create a DB (postgres) container and initialize a database from a `pg_dump file`. Does `ansible-containe`r respect the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`? I tried few variations with no luck so wondering if this is officially supported.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093801/deploy-ansible-project-which-include-a-docker-compose-yml

Answer (score 0):

Entrypoints are easy with ansible-container, but it's easier still if you are using roles.

In the service definition in container.yml put your entrypoint and command lines:

```
entrypoint: [/entrypoint.sh]
command: [/usr/bin/dumb-init, /opt/orson/mongo/bin/mongod --config /opt/orson/mongo/conf/mongod.conf]
```

Put a template of you entrypoint script in the templates folder of your role.
Bring the script into your service in the main.yml of your role.

```
- name: Template entrypoint script
  template: src="entrypoint.sh.j2" dest="/entrypoint.sh" mode=0777
```